# How to remove duplicate samba shared folders?

Tags: centos, windows, virtualbox

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/samba-server-installation-and-configuration-on-centos-7) to enable Samba service on CentOS 7 in Virtualbox, however it produces two same share folders with the only difference their name.

[image]

This is my samba.conf

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        server string = Samba Server %v
        netbios name = dev
        security = user
        map to guest = bad user
        dns proxy = no
        unix charset = UTF-8
        dos charset = CP932

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        browseable = No
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/tmp
        printable = Yes
        create mask = 0600
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
        write list = root
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775

[secured]
        path = /var/www/html
        valid users = @apache
        guest ok = no
        writable = yes
        browsable = yes
```

There is supposed one shared folder "`secured`", I don't understand why the "`apache`" , they both link to the same address "/var/www/html", any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, it's the homes section, which will create a samba user's home directory to a share folder automatically. As /var/www/html is the home directory of my apache user, that creates duplication

```
[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        browseable = No
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes
```

Comment: For what it's worth, unless you have users who actually need to get to their home directories via SMB, it's generally better to just remove that section (or comment it out) to minimize your external attack surface.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn, I have commented it out, thanks for the reminder.